# Describing a Turing machine that computes $\lceil\log_{2}(n)\rceil$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, automata

I need to describing a Turing machine that computes $\lceil\log_{2}(n)\rceil$ I know that:

n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ... 
f(n) = 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, ...

So I'm thinking of putting $n$ on the tape. Then keeping a count of how many times I multiply 2*2 until it is greater than than $n$. For example for n=5, 2*2*2=8, number of two's is 3 so then $f(n)$ is 3. I don't know how to translate this to the ticker tape of the Turing machine.

But would something like this work? Put $n$ 1's on the tape followed by a 0. Compute 1^(2^1), then check if 1's on the left of the 0 on the tape is less than or equal to the 1's on the right of the 0. If its not then repeat it for 1^(2^(1)). It keeps doing this until the left side has less than or equal number of 1's.

Comment: Do you know how to build a Turing machine that computes the product of two numbers?  Do you know how to build a Turing machine that computes $2^n$ (given $n$)?  If you have an algorithm in pseudocode, do you know how to convert it to a Turing machine?

Comment: Yes I know how to do the product and $2^n$. For the pseudocode it depends on what it does, im still trying to learn the Turing machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is:

1. Put $i \gets 0$ on the tape (store $i$ on the tape after $n$).
2. Compute $2^i$ (store it on the tape after $i$).
3. Check if $2^i \ge n$.  If yes, output $i$.  If no, increment $i$ and go to step 2.

You can work out the gory details on your own -- this is your exercise, after all!  This requires you to be able to compute $2^i$ (given $i$) and to be able to compute $i+1$ (given $i$), but it sounds like you already know how to do that.

Comment: Shouldn't 3. be check if $2^i>=n$. If n=8, f(n) is 3.

Comment: @DDInfo, that's a gory detail for you to figure out on your own.  It's your exercise! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can represent n by 1's in your tape, if n = 2 then you have 11
marks the beginning and the end of the tape to make it easier. Then for every two 1's erase the first and leave the 2nd.

I think the rest will be easy to figure out :)